# Teams for Linux snap application will not start

Tags: snap, ubuntu-gnome, .desktop

I recently installed Ubuntu 19.04 on my work laptop, and installed Teams for Linux snap for work purposes. Everything seemed to work perfectly at first, but at some point it stopped working. I can find the shortcut icon under Gnome's applications list, but nothing happens when I click it. Right clicking and selecting "Show details" returns the error message `Could not find "teams-for-linux_teams-for-linux.desktop"`. I tried to start the application from terminal to see if it returns any error messages, but absolutely nothing happens. When executing startup command, it simply returns to command prompt as shown below.

```
~$ teams-for-linux
~$
```

I've tried adding `--verbose`, `--v` and `-v` to see if this will return any feedback, but the result is the same. It simply returns to command prompt. Searching for through my hard drive for files named `*teams-for-linux*` in the name yields multiple locations, and I can only assume the application is installed.

```
~$ sudo find / -iname *teams-for-linux*
/tmp/snap.teams-for-linux
/tmp/snap.teams-for-linux/tmp/.snap/snap/teams-for-linux
/var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.teams-for-linux.teams-for-linux
/var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-update-ns.teams-for-linux
/var/lib/snapd/snapshots/2_teams-for-linux_0.7.0_62.zip
/var/lib/snapd/snapshots/4_teams-for-linux_0.7.0_62.zip
/var/lib/snapd/snapshots/3_teams-for-linux_0.7.0_62.zip
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/teams-for-linux_teams-for-linux.desktop
/var/lib/snapd/seccomp/bpf/snap.teams-for-linux.teams-for-linux.src
/var/lib/snapd/seccomp/bpf/snap.teams-for-linux.teams-for-linux.bin
/var/lib/snapd/cookie/snap.teams-for-linux
/var/lib/snapd/mount/snap.teams-for-linux.fstab
/var/lib/snapd/mount/snap.teams-for-linux.user-fstab
/var/lib/snapd/sequence/teams-for-linux.json
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/teams-for-linux_62.snap
/var/cache/apparmor/26b63962.0/snap.teams-for-linux.teams-for-linux
/var/cache/apparmor/26b63962.0/snap-update-ns.teams-for-linux
/var/snap/teams-for-linux
/home/[user]/.cache/gnome-software/odrs/io.snapcraft.teams-for-linux-IIAJhVGfBhm393UTagoW5awtZlPDGqHd.json
/home/[user]/snap/teams-for-linux
/etc/udev/rules.d/70-snap.teams-for-linux.rules
/run/snapd/ns/snap.teams-for-linux.fstab
/run/snapd/ns/teams-for-linux.mnt
/run/snapd/ns/snap.teams-for-linux.info
/run/snapd/lock/teams-for-linux.lock
/run/user/1000/snap.teams-for-linux
find: ‘/run/user/1000/doc’: Ikke tilgang
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Ikke tilgang
/run/udev/tags/snap_teams-for-linux_teams-for-linux
find: ‘/proc/2621/task/2621/net’: Ugyldig argument
find: ‘/proc/2621/net’: Ugyldig argument
/root/snap/teams-for-linux
/sys/fs/cgroup/devices/snap.teams-for-linux.teams-for-linux
/sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/snap.teams-for-linux
/snap/teams-for-linux
/snap/teams-for-linux/62/meta/gui/teams-for-linux.desktop
/snap/teams-for-linux/62/teams-for-linux
/snap/bin/teams-for-linux
```

I am at a loss here. Any advice on what the issue may be is most welcome.

Comment: According to the [`README.md`](https://github.com/IsmaelMartinez/teams-for-linux/blob/develop/app/config/README.md) there are a number of command line arguments. Try `teams-for-linux --help`. Does that do anything?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention that, but `teams-for linux --help` yield the same result: Nothing happens. :-(

Comment: You may want to post this as an issue on the Github page. It appears to me as a bug in the software.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've added [the issue to the GitHub page](https://github.com/IsmaelMartinez/teams-for-linux/issues/285#issue-500196728). =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the issue on the GitHub page. I was advised to [try install the deb package instead](https://github.com/IsmaelMartinez/teams-for-linux/issues/285#issuecomment-536543628). Installing from the deb package from [the GitHub downloads page](https://github.com/IsmaelMartinez/teams-for-linux/releases) worked, and I got Teams for Linux running (at least for now).

[Update 2021-08-19]

As per [Nicholoas Saunders' reply](https://askubuntu.com/a/1358285/800704), teams-for-linux snap application now seemingly works again. Presumably due to an update.

Since this question was posted [Microsoft has added Linux support to their official **Teams app**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/download-app). Consequently, [teams-for-linux is currently only maintained, and no longer developed](https://github.com/IsmaelMartinez/teams-for-linux#teams-for-linux). Therefore, it might be worth considering using Microsoft's official app moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.

For what it's worth, the command "works for me" on 21.04 when that specific version was installed via snap.

See:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ snap info teams-for-linux
name:      teams-for-linux
summary:   Unofficial Microsoft Teams client for Linux using Electron.
publisher: ismael (ismaelmartinez)
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/teams-for-linux
contact:   https://github.com/IsmaelMartinez/teams-for-linux
license:   unset
description: |
  Unofficial Microsoft Teams client for Linux using Electron. It uses the Web App and wraps it as a
  standalone application using Electron.
  
  Snap uses confinement to provide more security, this restrict the access to hardware or data on
  your device to prevent security issues.
commands:
  - teams-for-linux
snap-id:      IIAJhVGfBhm393UTagoW5awtZlPDGqHd
tracking:     latest/stable
refresh-date: 6 days ago, at 19:37 PDT
channels:
  latest/stable:    1.0.9 2021-07-13 (172) 74MB -
  latest/candidate: ↑                           
  latest/beta:      ↑                           
  latest/edge:      1.0.9 2021-07-15 (175) 74MB -
installed:          1.0.9            (172) 74MB -
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

Presumably the OP has since updated their OS.

I do notice that it's necessary to click the little icon in the top right to get a window.  But, definitely, running that command generates output very unlike that of the OP.

Comment: Tbh, I haven't used this application since Microsoft added support for Linux for their own Teams app. I was actually unaware that this app still is developed. Does it still hold relevance? If not, I will delete this post.

Comment: huh, I use it.  works fine.  am I using the wrong one or something?

Comment: Not really for me to say. I actually switched to the official app because the developer of Teams for Linux stated he would discontinue development after the official app was released. Let me rephrase myself: Does the teams-for-linux app offer any advantages over MS official app?

Comment: I didn't know that there was even an option @PålBjartan -- I thought there was just the one option.  I'm just glad to have the option.

Comment: [The official app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/download-app) in case you're interested.